# Wake up from sleep with GPIO (I2C)

Tags: 10.10, sleep, input-devices, wakeup

My situation:

- Ubuntu 10.10 running on an Atom driven main board
- The main board has a GPIO chip integrated (F75111 by Fintek).

They communicate through I2C (SMBus). We have a driver running that works, we can send outputs and read inputs. Great!

We would like to use the I/O interface to suspend (sleep) and wake up again.

Sleep is no problem. On an incoming input: run s2both. Ubuntu goes to sleep and prepares a hibernate state, so when the power-cord is unplugged by accident, it will wake from hibernate.

But the big question: how to wake on an input if the OS is already sleeping? You can wake from a lot of devices (LAN, USB, ring, etc) but I can't find out how to wake from a I2C card.

Please help.

Comment: Hi spambas, I have the same GPIO on my atom board and I do not know how to get it working or where to find a driver. Could you help me out with that? Should I open a new question?

Comment: Hi Goran, We used a document of Lexcomm, the manufacturer of our mainboard, as a reference: ftp://ftp.asmnet.cz/Lexcom/WDT_DIO_3I270_3I510_3I525/SDK/Linux/Howto%20Linux.txt I hope you can use this.